# Strange strings issue PayPal MPL

Tags: android, string, paypal

I'm using PayPal MPL and I see this:

[image]

It seems that the strings aren't showing correctly. I've changed the library for the one that uses the Demo that works correctly but my app is still showing stuff like the image.

What is happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: This is currently happening to me on S4. All other test devices are ok. Have you found a solution for this?